# It is possible to get both my public ipv4 and ipv6 addresses (whatsmyipaddresss.com can do it) How is this done?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

When accessing one of my sites on the www and displaying $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], sometimes it shows an ipv4 address, sometimes ipv6.  Fair enough.  I understand that the connection will be one or the other, not both.
But - I want to get both addresses.  Sites like whatsmyipaddress.com are able to show both.  Does anyone know how they are accomplishing this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Your public IPv6 address will be configured on the network interface of your host device. It is not like IPv4 where the public address may be different than your interface (Private) address.

Comment: Thanks... not sure that that answers anything.  My question amounts to, how do I get both my ipv4 and ipv6 addresses?  whatsmyipaddress.com etc give me both but I only know how to get one of them ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].  How do I get the other?  How do these other sites manage to obtain both?

Comment: That site looks at the source addresses on the packets received. You can easily get that from your own interface for IPv6, but it can be more difficult for IPv4 if NAPT is used, which is why you need something on the other side of the NAPT device to tell you what the public IPv4 address is. You do not need that for IPv6.

Comment: My question remains, if something on my home network asks something like whatsmyipaddress.com for my ip address, how does that site obtain both?  I want to replicate whatever it, and similar sites, are doing. "in the old days", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] was enough.  Now, most of the time, that just gives me an ipv6 address - and I know that it is possible to get both because all these ip address sites are able to do it.  When my site out on the www gets a request from my home network, what sort of query should I send where to get my ipv4 address?

Comment: As I explained, it gets your addresses from the source addresses on the packets it receives. I really do not know what you do not understand about that. Your source device does not know what the source address for IPv4 through NAT will be at the destination, but it can know what the IPv6 global address will be because it is the same as what is on your interface. The IPv6 part is easy, just look at the interface. The IPv4 part is hard because you need something on the other side of the NAT to tell you.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't explained the situation clearly.  I wish to write a script (of some sort) which will run on a webserver somewhere out on the www.  I want it to determine the ipv4 address of an incoming request (I don't care about ipv6 too much).

Comment: Are you saying that a request will contain both addresses (when both exist?)

Comment: "_I wish to write a script (of some sort) which will run on a webserver somewhere out on the www. I want it to determine the ipv4 address of an incoming request_" OK. I do not think anyone here is preventing you from doing that, but [so] is not a script-writing service. "_Are you saying that a request will contain both addresses (when both exist?)_" IPv4 packets will have both the IPv4 source (translated if on the other side of the NAT) and destination IPv4 addresses, and IPv6 packets will have both the source and destination IPv6 addresses.

Comment: That's fine;  I'm not asking anyone to write a script.  You have confirmed the point I made in my original question.  The packets will contain either ipv4 or ipv6 but not both.  My question was, how does the server, where the request arrives, get the other address?  It can be done because sites like whatsmyipaddress.com show both ipv4 and ipv6, despite the request only being in one or the other.  How do they obtain the other one?  If some light could be shed on that then I could think about how I might implement a similar solution.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. That site will get both IPv4 and IPv6 packets, and it determines the source addresses from the packets (which is what I have tried to explain multiple times). "_despite the request only being in one or the other._" One web page element only comes from one address, but there can be many web page elements from different sources. Some can be from IPv4 sources, and some can be from IPv6 sources.

Comment: I completely understand that the request address comes from the packets.  I'll put the rest of it another way:  Let's say that a router on a home network has an ipv4 and ipv6 address (as mine does).  Such a router makes one request to e.g. www.???.com/???.php  .  The packets will contain an ipv4 or 6 address, depending on which was used. How is that page at that site able to determine the other address?

Comment: You do not seem to understand how web pages work. You do not have a single request to load most web pages. Each element in a web page will get a separate request from your browser to load it. In general, you will open many TCP connections to different addresses to load a web page. You can look at the web page source, and you can use something like Wireshark to inspect the requests from your browser. I would suggest you learn more about how that stuff works first, before trying to program it.

Comment: I understand all that.  You appear to be saying that an element in a web page can force a request to be made using ipv4.  If that's the case then that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Of course an element can use a particular IP. For example, an element can have an IP address, and if the address is an IPv4 address, then the browser will use IPv4 to retrieve it, but if the element has an IPv6 address, then the browser will use IPv6 to retrieve it. That is very simple, basic HTML. Which IP an element uses is based on the version of the IP address.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote one of those "what is your IP address" services, at https://myip.addr.space/ so I can tell you exactly how it is done.

First, any single connection is only going to go over IPv6 or IPv4, but not both. It's impossible to get both addresses with a single request.

So, on the first request, we show the IPv6 or IPv4 address it came in on.

Next, we do some AJAX queries with jQuery, to subdomains that specifically have only an IPv4 address or only an IPv6 address, so that they only work on IPv4 or IPv6 respectively, and thus are guaranteed to return an IPv4 or IPv6 address.

This is done in the DNS like so:

```
$ host myip.addr.space
myip.addr.space is an alias for www.addr.space.
www.addr.space has address 144.217.146.101
www.addr.space has IPv6 address 2607:5300:203:118:1:0:3:8b50

$ host ipv4.myip.addr.space
ipv4.myip.addr.space has address 144.217.146.101

$ host ipv6.myip.addr.space
ipv6.myip.addr.space has IPv6 address 2607:5300:203:118:1:0:3:8b50
```

The jQuery is very simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$.get("https://ipv4.myip.addr.space/ajaxlookup")
.done(function(data) {
    $("div#ipv4-address").html(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    $("div#ipv4-address").html("<p>Couldn't determine an IPv4 address. You might not have IPv4 connectivity.</p>");
});
$.get("https://ipv6.myip.addr.space/ajaxlookup")
.done(function(data) {
    $("div#ipv6-address").html(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    $("div#ipv6-address").html("<p>Couldn't determine an IPv6 address. You might not have IPv6 connectivity.</p>");
});

</script>
```

This results in up to three IP address outputs:

[image: myip.addr.space]

What this doesn't do is to associate your IPv6 address with your IPv4 address. You'll need to use something like a cookie if you want to track a user as their IP address changes. There's nothing conceptually different here from how you would handle a user whose IPv4 address changed to a different IPv4 address, except perhaps that you have to throw out the practice of tying cookies to IP addresses if you had been doing that.

Comment: Wow this is excellent! I was looking for something like this for my own personal starting page to see both my IP-addresses. The only thing I do not understand is how the "/ajaxlookup" works? Will try a few things in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works without jQuery and uses a working API (10-2022)

Website: https://ip.lafibre.info/

```js
fetch ('https://ipv4.lafibre.info/ip.php').then(function(res) {return res.text();}).then(function(res) { alert(res)});
fetch ('https://ipv6.lafibre.info/ip.php').then(function(res) {return res.text();}).then(function(res) { alert(res)});
```